# Connection pooling for JAX-WS client on websphere

Tags: java, connection, websphere, jax-ws, pooling

As per IBM websphere documentation , once we declare maxconnection and conenction timeout in JVM custome properties. Connction pool will throw an exception if there are no more connection left in the conenction pool and connection timeout also occurs meanwhile. For testing the same I have specified max conenction as 1 and connection timeout as 2 seconds.Plus , I am giving delay of 8 seconds in my implementation class. On making 15 -20 concurrent request, I have noticed that all the request are getting served without throwing any exception though I have also give keepAlive property as false.This entire scnerio seems to contradictory with implementaion given in IBM documentation .

Please let me know if any of faced the same issue and have any solution for the same.